# Binary Search - Error

Tags: java, binary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I have a list of students, and i would like to sort them by the last name.
The student list looks a bit like this:

```
Amanda
Dorris
Tucker
Yasmin
Zara
```

I would like to use the binary search approach to search through these students and output the desired result.

This is what i have so far:

```
public void binarySearch(String keyword) {

    int output;

    if (fileSorted == false) {
        System.out.println("The file " + fileName + " is not sorted. Please wait while it gets sorted...");
        bubbleSort();
        System.out.println("Thank you for your patience.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Search for: ");
        keyword = elmo.nextLine();
        output = doBinarySearch(keyword);
    } else {
        output = doBinarySearch(keyword);
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}

public int doBinarySearch(String keyword) {

    int start = 0;
    int end = numStudents - 1;
    int mid;
    int result;

    while (start < end) {
        mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        result = students[mid].returnLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(keyword);

        if (result == 0) {
            return mid;
        } else if ((end - start) <= 1 ) {
            return -1;
        } else if (result > 0) {
            start = mid;
        } else if (result < 0) {
            end = mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What happens that isn't what you expect?  In other words, what specifically is the problem?

Comment: System.out.println(output);
not giving me the output. the program dies :(

Comment: What does mean "the program dies"? Usually you get an exception message with valuable information. Please post it.

Comment: A stacktrace with the error would be useful

Comment: after i enter the keyword, i get no reply from the program...

Comment: Then this is more an infinite loop in `doBinarySearch` than an error in `System.out.println`.

Comment: when i take out the while loop, i get the output as -1

Comment: any idea on how to fix the while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
mid = ((end - start) / 2);
```

is wrong. You need to set `mid` to (roughly) the midpoint of `start` and `end`, so

```
mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
```

or

```
mid = (end + start) / 2;
```

if you're not afraid of overflow.

With what you have, `mid` is always in the first half of the array.

Also, you have your cases

```
    } else if (result > 0) {
        start = mid;
    } else if (result < 0) {
        end = mid;
    }
```

wrong.

```
result = students[mid].returnLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(keyword);
```

returns a positive number when the last name of `students[mid]` is lexicographically greater than `keyword`, so then you need to change `end`, not `start`.

Comment: Interesting. I fixed the mid error. What do i do to fix my cases?

Comment: Just swap the comparisons. You can also use `mid-1` and `mid+1`, `else if (result < 0) { start = mid+1; } else { end = mid-1; }` since you know `mid` is not the correct index.

Comment: And instead of `if (end - start <= 1)`, you should use `if (end <= start)`. If `end == start+1`, `mid` is set to `start`, and if `end` is a match, you never try that with the test you have now.

Comment: I would go with Daniel Fisher's answer. As well check your **while** loop, because this might not check for the last name in the data.

Comment: Awesome. It actually makes so much sense to me now! But there is one thing that is bugging me, the first element, Amanda, and the last element, zara, isnt being outputted when i search for it. The rest is good.

Comment: To find Zara, you actually _need_ to set `start = mid+1;` (and only stop when `end <= start`) when `students[mid]` is too small. Have you done that? I don't see what would cause Amanda to be missed, some tracing output could help. Also, make sure that the names are exactly what they should be, not that they contain a newline or something.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inequality in your loop condition -- `while (start != end)` -- use `while (start < end)`. [This is the typical approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). When you test for equality, you make the assumption that `start` and `end` only change by one in each iteration, and that may not necessarily be true.

Comment: It is easy to understand that the data gets sorted in `bubbleSort` if it was not marked as previously sorted by `fileSorted`. We do not want some hundreds of code lines here. I agree that `while (start < end)` is more appropiate, though.

Comment: I agree, and have edited my answer. I'm just concerned about what is happening to the data before it gets to the search method.